# OpenCV Cascade Classifier Tutorial Exception

Tags: visual-studio-2008, opencv, object-detection

I am new to OpenCV and C++. I got OpenCV working with Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 (32-bits) and managed to get the [Filtering Tutorial](http://opencv.itseez.com/doc/tutorials/imgproc/gausian_median_blur_bilateral_filter/gausian_median_blur_bilateral_filter.html#smoothing)/ [Sobel Derivatives](http://opencv.itseez.com/doc/tutorials/imgproc/imgtrans/sobel_derivatives/sobel_derivatives.html#sobel-derivatives) and other tutorials to work.

I am now trying the [Cascade Classifier tutorial](http://opencv.itseez.com/doc/tutorials/objdetect/cascade_classifier/cascade_classifier.html#cascade-classifier) using the code they supply in the tutorial:

```
 #include "opencv2/objdetect/objdetect.hpp"
 #include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
 #include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"

 #include <iostream>
 #include <stdio.h>

 using namespace std;
 using namespace cv;

 /** Function Headers */
 void detectAndDisplay( Mat frame );

 /** Global variables */
 String face_cascade_name = "haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml";
 String eyes_cascade_name = "haarcascade_eye_tree_eyeglasses.xml";
 CascadeClassifier face_cascade;
 CascadeClassifier eyes_cascade;
 string window_name = "Capture - Face detection";
 RNG rng(12345);

 /** @function main */
 int main( int argc, const char** argv )
 {
   CvCapture* capture;
   Mat frame;

   //-- 1. Load the cascades
   if( !face_cascade.load( face_cascade_name ) ){ printf("--(!)Error loading\n"); return -1; };
   if( !eyes_cascade.load( eyes_cascade_name ) ){ printf("--(!)Error loading\n"); return -1; };

   //-- 2. Read the video stream
   capture = cvCaptureFromCAM( -1 );
   if( capture )
   {
     while( true )
     {
       frame = cvQueryFrame( capture );

       //-- 3. Apply the classifier to the frame
       if( !frame.empty() )
       { detectAndDisplay( frame ); }
       else
       { printf(" --(!) No captured frame -- Break!"); break; }

       int c = waitKey(10);
       if( (char)c == 'c' ) { break; }
      }
   }
   return 0;
 }

/** @function detectAndDisplay */
void detectAndDisplay( Mat frame )
{
  std::vector<Rect> faces;
  Mat frame_gray;

  cvtColor( frame, frame_gray, CV_BGR2GRAY );
  equalizeHist( frame_gray, frame_gray );

  //-- Detect faces
  face_cascade.detectMultiScale( frame_gray, faces, 1.1, 2, 0|CV_HAAR_SCALE_IMAGE, Size(30, 30) );

  for( int i = 0; i < faces.size(); i++ )
  {
    Point center( faces[i].x + faces[i].width*0.5, faces[i].y + faces[i].height*0.5 );
    ellipse( frame, center, Size( faces[i].width*0.5, faces[i].height*0.5), 0, 0, 360, Scalar( 255, 0, 255 ), 4, 8, 0 );

    Mat faceROI = frame_gray( faces[i] );
    std::vector<Rect> eyes;

    //-- In each face, detect eyes
    eyes_cascade.detectMultiScale( faceROI, eyes, 1.1, 2, 0 |CV_HAAR_SCALE_IMAGE, Size(30, 30) );

    for( int j = 0; j < eyes.size(); j++ )
     {
       Point center( faces[i].x + eyes[j].x + eyes[j].width*0.5, faces[i].y + eyes[j].y + eyes[j].height*0.5 );
       int radius = cvRound( (eyes[j].width + eyes[i].height)*0.25 );
       circle( frame, center, radius, Scalar( 255, 0, 0 ), 4, 8, 0 );
     }
  }
  //-- Show what you got
  imshow( window_name, frame );
 }
```

I have added these libraries to the Linker Input:
**opencv_core230d.lib
opencv_calib3d230d.lib
opencv_contrib230d.lib
opencv_features2d230d.lib
opencv_highgui230d.lib
opencv_legacy230d.lib
opencv_ml230d.lib
opencv_imgproc230d.lib
opencv_video230d.lib
opencv_objdetect230.lib
opencv_gpu230d.lib
opencv_haartraining_engined.lib**

And I have the xml files in the main directory of my Visual Studio Project (where the solution file resides)

But I get the following error when I run/debug:

**

```
First-chance exception at 0x76b1b9bc in OpenCV_CascadeClassifier.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: cv::Exception at memory location 0x002ff1d0..
Unhandled exception at 0x77e315de in OpenCV_CascadeClassifier.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: cv::Exception at memory location 0x002ff1d0..
```

**

It doesn't show a line of code that is wrong but points me to a memory locations and shows me Disassembly code which I don't understand.

***Question:*** How do I get the video stream from my webcam to communicate with the OpenCV code in Visual Studio? Is that what the problem is or am I missing something else?

**EDIT**: The error actually happens in the first line of loading the cascades. I have tried placing the cascade xmls in different places with no success.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

you connect your video stream to OpenCV through the following calls:

```
capture = cvCaptureFromCAM( -1 );
```

and

```
frame = cvQueryFrame( capture );
```

The first call will set your camera up - it will pick any available - and the second one will retrieve the frames. The code makes lots of assumptions when it goes wrong, so it's hard to tell the source of the problems.

My advice would be to run the code in Debug mode (set a breakpoint in the first line), copy the xmls to the right place - you will probably need to put it in your Debug folder or as the project root - and go line by line until the exception is thrown. After that you can tell us in which line that happened and we can solve the problem for good.

Kind regards,
Daniel

Comment: Hi dannyxyz22, Thanks for your response. I debugged and the code seems to complain at the first load xml line: ' if( !face_cascade.load( face_cascade_name ) ){ printf("--(!)Error loading\n"); return -1; };'

Comment: I have tried placing the xml files in 4 different locations. (including the two Debug folders)

Comment: I have also tried to specify the complete path C:\Users ...etc for the xml files and I still got a similar error.

Comment: the cam index differs in different systems, "-1" can only be used if there is only one camera or doesn't matter which camera it uses. I never got this to work in my system.

Comment: I have previously solved the "cascade path" issues by keeping the cascade.xml's in the script directory.

Comment: What Scripts Folder? @KishorKundan  Do I have to create one in VS 2008?

Comment: i use the python version of opencv, and unless the cascade was kept in the directory where my python script resided i couldn't get it working. no sure if this will help for C#

Comment: How did you specify the path? Are you using backslashes? If you are, make sure you type \\ instead of a single \. Eg: C:\\haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml